# xamarin.forms page navigation is too slow

Tags: xamarin.forms

My page has following hierarchy.

```
<Grid>

<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row = 0>
    // Contains header
</AbsoluteLayout>

<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row = 1>
    <Scrollview>
        <Grid>
            <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row = 0>
             // Contains Image
            </AbsoluteLayout>
            <Grid>
               <ListView Grid.Row = 0>
                // I know its not good thing to use listview inside scrollview but I have to use it.
               </ListView>
               <Button Grid.Row = 1 Text = "Add Item1"/>
            </Grid>
             <Grid>
               <ListView Grid.Row = 0>

               </ListView>
               <Button Grid.Row = 1 Text = "Add Item2"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Scrollview>
</AbsoluteLayout>

<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row = 2>
    // Contains Footer
</AbsoluteLayout>
</Grid>
```

Now when I navigate to this page on click of button it takes around 3-4 seconds to load which is I think too much.

I have used only 2 `StackLayout` in footer because I read that `Stacklayout` slows down the application.

Is there any other way so that I can speed up my navigation ?

EDIT - It takes 1 second to jump from constructor to OnAppearing(). In OnAppeaeing() I fill the lists shown in code.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on a specific platform (e.g., iOS, Android), or on all of them? Also, which version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?

Comment: Is it a release or debug issue? Does your output window say something like doing too much work on the main thread? Are you doing anything in the page constructor?

Comment: @E.Z.Hart I have not checked on iOS device yet. I am using android device. And I am using latest version of xamarin.forms

Comment: @Rohit It is debugg issue. I call two methods in constructor for data binding. And my output window shows 'skipped 124 frames! The application may be doing too much work on the main thread.'

Comment: Can you provide the C# code behind this design?